# Compact framework- Capture incoming call phone event

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I working in .Net Compact Framework. I am losing all my working data if I receive phone call. I want to capture incoming call event and save all my data and retrieve it back when I hanged up. I their is any possibilities I can do that. 
I found TAPI would suit for this but I am not sure how to use. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just handle the loss of focus in your app?